# Use variable in task_id or task hover to uniquely identify task of each request

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I want a way to somehow add variable value in task hover or in task_id to uniquely identify execution for a request. Below is my workflow.

PubSubPullSensor -> TriggerDagOperator.

In my workflow i am getting unique request Id through pub/sub which i want to use to uniquely identify request as there might be multiple request in one day.

I have tries putting variable in templated fields and task_id but that are treated as static values and not changing as per new id

EDIT---

@HusseinAwala Apologies for late message. Code goes something like below. What i am trying to do here is get one ID through variable and use it in

```
task_id to uniquely identify task
default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(year=2022, month=11, day=1)
}

with DAG( 'watch_messages_dev_7_0', default_args=default_args, description='Monitor pub sub messages', catchup=False, max_active_runs=1) as Watchdag:
    pub_sub_sensor = PubSubPullSensor(task_id='pull-messages',
                                      max_messages=50,
                                      ack_messages=True,
                                      project_id=project,
                                      subscription=subscription,
                                      poke_interval=5,
                                      on_failure_callback=_failure_callback)

    variable_setting = PythonOperator(
        task_id=f"set-veriables",
        python_callable=decode_message,
        op_args=['pull-messages'],
    )
    v_list = Variable.get("request_id", deserialize_json=True)

    create_solr_cluster = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id=f'create_cluster'+{v_list},
        trigger_dag_id="create_solr_cluster_dev_7_3",
        trigger_run_id=datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+"_"+str(v_list)     )
```

Comment: `task_id` is not a template field, so you cannot change its value in runtime, could you provide some code to let us understand your needs in order to help you?

Comment: Sure, I will send here.

Comment: @HusseinAwala I have added code snippet in question